# Angular testing not invoking expectation resulting to "Spec has no expectation"

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have service that makes an HTTP call to my backend, I'm trying to test if it will get a users response, upon running the test I get a `Spec has no expectation` even though I have one inside a subscription. All of these test passes but 2 has an output of `SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATION`

here's my code:

```
describe('Auth Service Testing', () => {
  let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };
  let authServ: AuthService;
  let authAct: AuthActions;
  let userAct: UserActions;
  let checkoutAct: CheckoutActions;
  let productAct: ProductActions;
  let store: Store<any>;
  let localStorageServ: LocalStorageService;
  let authResponse;
  const expectedUserResponse = {
    users: [],
    count: 25,
    current_page: 1,
    pages: 2
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
    authServ = new AuthService(
      <any>httpClientSpy,
      authAct,
      userAct,
      checkoutAct,
      productAct,
      store,
      localStorageServ
    );
  });

  it('should get users response', () => {
    httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncData(expectedUserResponse));

    authServ.authorized().subscribe((users) => {
      authResponse = users;
      expect(users).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({ users: [] }));
    });

  });

  it('should equal to expected users response', () => {
    expect(authResponse).toEqual(expectedUserResponse);
  });

  it('should return null if theres an error', () => {
    httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncError(expectedUserResponse));
    authServ
      .authorized()
      .subscribe(() => {}, (error) => expect(error).toBe(null));
  });
});
```

also, I followed the angular HTTP testing guide [angular test](https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests)
I'm wondering if this is a bug or something else.

karma results:

```
Auth Service Testing
SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should return null if there's an error
SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should get users response
should equal to expected users response
```

**UPDATE**

The code that is missing is this `expect(httpClientSpy.get.calls.count()).toBe(1);` this is weird, I thought this call makes an http get request `httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncError(expectedUserResponse));`

but on the error test on the guide, they don't have this though. Can someone shed light on this one?

much love from North Korea. <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really difficult to unit test an observable using a subscription. There are many edge cases where the unit test will pass, but should have failed. Even if you use the `done()` callback with a finiazlier or error handler.

Whenever an observable emits only *one* expected result, then you should use a promise instead.

```js
  it('should get users response', async () => {
    httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncData(expectedUserResponse));

    const users = await = authServ.authorized().toPromise();

    expect(users).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({ users: [] }));
  });
```

Whenever an observable emits multiple values, then you can convert to an array and still use a promise.

```js
  it('should get users response', async () => {
    httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(asyncData(expectedUserResponse));

    const users = await = authServ.authorized().pipe(
        toArray()
    ).toPromise();

    expect(users).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining([{ users: [] }]));
  });
```

The advantage of `toPromise()` is that it always resolves. Even if no values are emitted by the observable, and it fails the unit test if any uncaught errors are thrown inside the observable.

Comment: this one works but why is it angular documentation recommend this though. this is much easier and simple. So every time I test for any observables I use `toPromise()`

Comment: @aRtoo I know, but the documentation is wrong. Their examples can fail. That's the difference between experience and theory. `o.subscribe(v => expect(v).toBe(1), () => done.fail(), ()=> done());` will *pass* if `o` never emits.

Comment: I've been reading an angular post and ive read about the complaints about subscribing to an HTTP response, so it's true then or its just for testing. thank you again sir. you are the goat.

Comment: @aRtoo it is only for unit testing, and it's because of how rxjs handles emitting of data and completion as separate events. So an observable can complete, might not complete and might not emit anything. A unit test developer has to handle these edge cases, and must people don't. So it makes for some bad unit tests, but switching to promises simplifies the work for you. It doesn't mean you should use promises in your application instead of observables.

Comment: thank you so much. this clarify everything now. I will keep this in mind. appreciate the help sir.